# Does a tertiary carbocation rearrange to another tertiary carbocation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

I strongly believe that a carbocation should not rearrange to another if there are no **immediate** benefits(like a [Greedy Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm)).

[image: reaction and possible products]

The doubt hit me while solving this question. The answer mentioned in the book answers (b) but my answer comes out to be (a).

Here is the mechanism:

[image: mechanism]

Comment: Ring expansion step gives you secondary carbocation, which is in higher energy state than original tertiary carbocation.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I am talking about the first shift.

Comment: Ring expansion and release of some strain presumably outweighs going from a tertiary to secondary carbocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option B is the correct one. The process of dehydration of alcohols follow E1 elimination mechanism which involves two steps out of which the first one is slow ionisation of C-X bond( where X is any hetro atom) and the second step is  fast removal of $H^+$ ion .Since the first step is slow it provides enough time for the carbocation to rearrange and form a stable carbocation . The mechanism itself is self explanatory. Firstly as Oxygen possess lone pairs of electrons so the $H^+$ ion attacks the OH group as a result the $H_2O $ molecular gets eliminated resulting in a positive charge there.  Now hydride shift takes place as the so formed $ \textbf{Carbocation is more stable as it has 7 alpha hydrogens compared to the 5 alpha hydrogens of the previous carbocation}$. Now the C-C bond undergoes ionisation to form a three degree Carbocation and a carbanion . Now this carbanion forms a bond with the Carbocation formed earlier to form a six member ring . Now the resulting carbocation undergoes methyl shift which produces more stable three degree Carbocation. Now a $H^+$ ion from the neighbouring carbon atom is ejected as a result the pie bond is formed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes b is the correct answer.

The carbocation will do a hydride shift to the tertiary carbon. It will then have a ring expansion. Then it will have a methyl shift. It will then lose its H+ ion to give option b.

Actually its forming a much stable product on hydride shift. Ergo it does shift to another tertiary carbon